# Is there are resource that will render a milepost number for a geographic coordinate?

Tags: java, ios, google-maps, geocoding

I have a client that wants two different kinds of Events together in one table sorted by their position on a highway.

Events of type X always have a number that represents relative position on the highway. Only about half of them also have milepost data.

Events of type Y only have milepost data.

All events have lat-long coordinates and know which highway they're on.

I was wondering if there is some resource out there that will get me a milepost number if I know the coordinates and highway. This way I can just sort all events by their milepost number.

The table is on an iOS app, but I do a lot of preprocessing using an external java program.

Answer (score 0):

Many interstates use mile numbers as exit numbers - for those states you may be able to use that information to help narrow down locations. I'm guessing that one of the Google Maps APIs will help you get where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial here on estimating latitude and longitude positions from mileposts, and vice-versa: http://enholm.net/2017/12/22/milepost-gis-location-estimation-r/